# unsupported pseudo: in-viewport

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagepiling.js

I'm following [this guide](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/scroll-linked-navigation/) to detect when my video element comes in viewport then do "x", but keep getting the title error. Not sure if because Im using wordpress with gulp and [piling.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js/)

My page uses Piling and I have a video section, when I scroll to that "stack", I want the video to start play but it starts to play on page load.

```
// inside document.ready()

 $('video').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
        $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
    }
})
```

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: in-viewport

```
<div id='<ID-CHANGES-INSIDE-LOOP>' class='image-block'>
  <video autoplay>
    <source class='video' src='movie.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
</div>
```

Is using Piling making this difficult to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [pagePiling.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js#callbacks) or state classes.

Answer (score 4):

That pseudo selector needs its plugin to work (it's not part of jQuery selectors), but nowadays you can easily check if an element is in the viewport using `.getBoundingClientRect()`. Here's the method I use:

```
/**
 * Check if an element is in the visible viewport
 * @param {jQuery|HTMLElement} el
 * @return boolean
 */
var IsInViewport = function(el) {
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) el = el[0];
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};

// example
if( IsInViewport($('#myvideo')) ) { /* do stuff.. */ }
```

Also, depending on your needs, you could use `:visible` selector (https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: Hi. Im getting `Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined`. My bad. yes this worked. Thnaks

Comment: How about not in view port?

Comment: I was seeking for an example that I've made previously that pretty matches what you're looking for. Hope it works for you: https://jsfiddle.net/3frk6u58/

Comment: About negation, `IsInViewport()` returns a boolean so you can do just `!IsInViewport(/*...*/)`

Comment: Hi, the answer was to use pagepiling callback which worked. However, I have much use for your code. Thanks. Here's an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

the pseudo property `:in-viewport` needs to be attached by a plugin (which I cannot find anymore) -

maybe try the try the [OnScreen](http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html) Basic Visibility Detection instead; it does about the same.